# Find specific string objects in text

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-mining, information-extraction

Lets say that I have a free text filled with information about specific cars, car brands and other automative-related information. I want to extract this information from the text following a certain template:

- **Brand:**
- **Model:**
- **Color:**

For example: "Mike drove away in a black Mercedes with four other people. Moreover he also owns a BMW M3 in Europe."

*Template 1: Brand: Mercedes, Model: -, Color: Black*

*Template 2: Brand: BMW, Model: M3, Color: -*

What is the best way to tackle this in Python? Although I have some knowledge about NLTK, POS tagging and NP-chunking, I am thinking it could be done I an easier way once I can recognize specific terms, from for example a (nested) dictionary that contains lists. As such, it would behave like a controlled vocabulary.

Hopefully, someone has a nice example or can point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Could you add text examples?

Comment: Add the text file or sample of text file

Comment: edited the question

Comment: You must have some data structure where you can store brand, model, color.

Comment: there can be 3 methods. 1) Regular expressions 2) NER and looking for data in specific NER tags 3) Building an information extraction module using techniques such CRF, RNN etc. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

> **Assumption**:
>
> > 1. You have a dictionary like this:
> >        Brand = ['Mercedes', 'BMW']
> >        Model = ['M3']
> >        Color = ['black']
> > 2. The three Keywords have allways the following order in the text:
> >        Color Brand Model

Using your example `text`, I got the following result:

```
words = text.split(' ')
templates = []
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if word in Brand:
        template = {'Brand': None, 'Model': None, 'Color': None}
        template['Brand'] = word
        if words[i-1] in Color:
            template['Color'] = words[i-1]
        if words[i+1] in Model:
            template['Model'] = words[i+1]

        templates.append( template )

print(templates)

[{'Brand': 'Mercedes', 'Model': None, 'Color': 'black'}, {'Brand': 'BMW', 'Model': 'M3', 'Color': None}]
```